# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor @string dot problem

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

With the MVC3 Razor synax, one may render a string like so

```
@ViewData("photo")
```

My problem is: How can I append a dot to the above code.
The following will result in a "Public member 'jpg' on type 'String' not found.":

```
@ViewData("photo").jpg
```

I've tried the following code but does not produce my intended result:

```
@ViewData("photo") .jpg
@ViewData("photo"):.jpg
@ViewData("photo") & ".jpg"
```

Thanx for advance for your help.
And please dont advice me to append the "jpg" in the controller's code like so:

```
ViewData("photo") = "filename.jpg"
```

I've searched the Net for the same problem but found none, not even something

similar.
By the way, I'm using VB.net.

Comment: Wouldn't @(ViewData("photo") + ".jpg") work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding as answer:

@(ViewData("photo") + ".jpg")

Comment: Thankx for giving the correct answer. @Jesper Palm and @JP also gave the correct answer but manojlds answered first

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
@(ViewData("photo")).jpg
```

Edit: And with the dynamic ViewBag:

```
@(ViewBag.photo).jpg
```

Comment: I would argue that this is the quickest and most efficient method

Answer (score 0):

You could always try:

@string.concat(ViewData("photo"),".jpg")